# search max value in multiple csv files

Tags: python, csv

Please excuse the beginner's question; I have search the site but similar questions seem to involve SQL and I would like to learn how to do this with Python alone.

Ok, so I have figured out how to print the max value with cvs.reader

Here is my code so far:

```
with open('/users/user/Documents/test.csv', 'rU') as f:
f_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in f_csv:
    max_row = max(csv.reader(f), key=op.itemgetter(0))
    print max_row
```

This return the row with the highest value in my csv file
But what I truly need is to compare multiple csv files and to find the max value in all of them (or better yet, the top 5), and return not the row but the name of the file. 
For example, if I have 2 csv files, with the name and age of students in two separate classes, the code will find the max value and return the class with the oldest student in it (file name).

Can anyone please help? Thanks!

Andre

Answer (score 1):

Try this example and illustrate with your requirement

```
import csv
import operator as op
import requests

symbol = "mtgoxUSD"
url = 'http://api.bitcoincharts.com/v1/trades.csv?symbol={}'.format(symbol)
csv_file = "trades_{}.csv".format(symbol)

data = requests.get(url)
with open(csv_file, "w") as f:
    f.write(data.text)

with open(csv_file) as f:
    next(f) # discard first row from file -- see notes
    max_value = max(row[0] for row in csv.reader(f))

with open(csv_file) as f:
    next(f) # discard first row from file -- see notes
    max_row = max(csv.reader(f), key=op.itemgetter(0))
```

Notes:

max() can directly consume an iterator, and csv.reader() gives us an iterator, so we can just pass that in. I'm assuming you might need to throw away a header line so I showed how to do that. If you had multiple header lines to discard, you might want to use islice() from the itertools module.

In the first one, we use a "generator expression" to select a single value from each row, and find the max. This is very similar to a "list comprehension" but it doesn't build a whole list, it just lets us iterate over the resulting values. Then max() consumes the iterable and we get the max value.

max() can use a key= argument where you specify a "key function". It will use the key function to get a value and use that value to figure the max... but the value returned by max() will be the unmodified original value (in this case, a row value from the CSV). In this case, the key function is manufactured for you by operator.itemgetter()... you pass in which column you want, and operator.itemgetter() builds a function for you that gets that column.

The resulting function is the equivalent of:

```
def get_col_0(row):
    return row[0]
max_row = max(csv.reader(f), key=get_col_0)
```

Or, people will use lambda for this:

```
max_row = max(csv.reader(f), key=lambda row: row[0])
```

But I think operator.itemgetter() is convenient and nice to read. And it's fast.

I showed saving the data in a file, then pulling from the file again. If you want to go through the data without saving it anywhere, you just need to iterate over it by lines.
Perhaps something like:

```
text = data.text
rows = [line.split(',') for line in text.split("\n") if line]
rows.pop(0)  # get rid of first row from data
max_value = max(row[0] for row in rows)
max_row = max(rows, key=op.itemgetter(0))
```

Comment: One more thing if you do not mind, would that code also work if I need to compare more than 2 excels/csv files? Thanks again!